# Distorted animation of skinned model from gltf

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl, gltf, skinning

I am exploring importing models from `gltf` files. I was able to render the mesh directly, and in the next iteration I am able to render a skinned model. I am creating a tree of nodes (so the ancestry is clear) and I create `local_TRS` matrix for each joint based on their respective translation, rotation and scale.
Based on the [tutorial](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_020_Skins.md):

```
jointMatrix(j) =
  globalTransformOfJointNode(j) *
  inverseBindMatrixForJoint(j);
```

Relevant parts of the code so far, to create joint matrices:

```
  applyTRS(joint, animation_matrix) {
    const parentTRS = joint.parent ? joint.parent.global_TRS : glMatrix.mat4.create();
    const animMatrix = animation_matrix[joint.jointIndex];
    glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, parentTRS, joint.local_TRS); // skin matrix
    //glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, joint.global_TRS, animMatrix); //this one ruins it

    for (const child of joint.children) {
      this.applyTRS(child, animation_matrix);
    }
    glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, joint.global_TRS, joint.InverseBindMatrix);
  }
```

And extraction of `u_jointMat` for shader uniform:

```
  makeJointMatrix(joint) {
    const matrix = this.skin.jointMatrix;
    const skinJoints = this.skin.skinJoints;
    const index = skinJoints.indexOf(joint.index) * 16;
    glMatrix.mat4.copy(matrix.subarray(index, index + 16), joint.global_TRS);
    for (const child of joint.children) {
      this.makeJointMatrix(child);
    }
  }
```

And finally, the vertex shader code:

```
///model_vShader///
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif

const int MAX_JOINTS = 64;

attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec4 aJoint;
attribute vec4 aWeight;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 uScale;
uniform mat4 uTranslate;
uniform mat4 uRotateY;
uniform mat4 u_jointMat[MAX_JOINTS];

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 FragPos;
varying vec3 v_normal;

void main(void) {
    mat4 skinMat = aWeight.x * u_jointMat[int(aJoint.x)] +
        aWeight.y * u_jointMat[int(aJoint.y)] +
        aWeight.z * u_jointMat[int(aJoint.z)] +
        aWeight.w * u_jointMat[int(aJoint.w)];

    vec4 position = skinMat * aVertexPosition;
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * uTranslate * uRotateY * uScale * position;
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    //FragPos = vec3(aVertexPosition);
    FragPos = vec3(position); //? no effect yet?
    //v_normal = aVertexNormal;
    v_normal = vec3(skinMat * vec4(aVertexNormal, 0.0)); //? no effect yet?
}
```

This correctly renders the skinned model in resting pose as seen below (with ugly textured 'Cesium man'):
[image: Skinned model]

With the inclusion of animation data, which is interpolated and converted to corresponding TRS matrices `animationMatrix`:

```
animate(date) {
    const A = this.animations[this.animationIndex];
    const delta = ((date - this.birth) / 1000) % A.nodes[0].max;
    let keyFrameIndex = -1;
    let KFL = null;
    let keyFrameTime = 0;
    const animationMatrix = new Array(Object.keys(A.nodes).length);
    for (let nodeIndex in A.nodes) {
      const node = A.nodes[nodeIndex];
      if (!(keyFrameIndex >= 0 && KFL === node.time.length && keyFrameTime === node.time[keyFrameIndex])) {
        KFL = node.time.length;
        keyFrameIndex = binarySearchClosestLowFloat(node.time, delta, node.max / KFL);
        keyFrameTime = node.time[keyFrameIndex];
      }
      const nextKeyFrameTime = node.time[keyFrameIndex + 1];
      const timeScale = (delta - keyFrameTime) / (nextKeyFrameTime - keyFrameTime);

      const translation = glMatrix.vec3.create();
      glMatrix.vec3.lerp(translation, node.translation[keyFrameIndex], node.translation[keyFrameIndex + 1], timeScale);

      const rotation = glMatrix.quat.create();
      glMatrix.quat.slerp(rotation, node.rotation[keyFrameIndex], node.rotation[keyFrameIndex + 1], timeScale);

      const scale = glMatrix.vec3.create();
      glMatrix.vec3.lerp(scale, node.scale[keyFrameIndex], node.scale[keyFrameIndex + 1], timeScale);

      const TRS = glMatrix.mat4.create();
      glMatrix.mat4.fromRotationTranslationScale(TRS, rotation, translation, scale);
      animationMatrix[node.jointIndex] = TRS;
    }
    A.animationMatrix = animationMatrix;
    const parentJoint = this.skin.joint;
    this.applyTRS(parentJoint, A.animationMatrix);
    this.makeJointMatrix(parentJoint);
  }
```

If I uncomment this line in the `applyTRS` method:

```
glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, joint.global_TRS, animMatrix); //this one ruins it
```

The model becomes distorted, as shown below. What is not clear from the picture is that animation seems correct, feet and hands move as expected however the model I rotated unexpectedly, raised up, and relation between joins is unnatural (like the body was thrown from the building ...).

[image: animated model]

It seems like I am missing another matrix, to put it back into place. Maybe the cryptic `inverse(globalTransform)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029821/4154250):

```
M_joint(i) = inverse(globalTransform) * M_global(i) * inverseBindMatrix(i)
```

So how can I make the animation work; what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
applyTRS(joint, animation_matrix) {
    const parentTRS = joint.parent ? joint.parent.global_TRS : glMatrix.mat4.create();
    const animMatrix = animation_matrix[joint.jointIndex];
    glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, parentTRS, animMatrix); // this works!
    for (const child of joint.children) {
      this.applyTRS(child, animation_matrix);
    }
    glMatrix.mat4.multiply(joint.global_TRS, joint.global_TRS, joint.InverseBindMatrix);
  }
```

I was wrong before, I didn't need to transform `local_TRS` with `animation_matrix`. In animation, `local_TRS` is TRS from `animation_matrix`, as seen in the code above. Now it works.

[image: Works]